# modelling interfaces between applications in archimate and visual paradigm

Tags: visual-paradigm, archimate

I am evaluating VisualParadigm 14.1 currently.

What is the easiest (but semantically correct) way to model the following in VP 14.1

"Application A" sends "Data D" via "Interface I" to "Application B"

using these archimate model elements:

[image: application model elements]

Background: I have that information (applications, interfaces and data) in Excel and want to use VP to draw the diagrams (and eventually host the model). As long as Excel is the primary source for me I have to go for Excel import/export ...
Please note that I am new to Archimate and VP (but not to modelling).

Edit: additional info: I used the proposed connections from the diagram, but I can draw a "usedBy" link between two components. I can call it by the data that flows. But is this semantically correct in archimate ?

[image: a simple data flow between application components]

Comment: I assume you don't mean the Sparx product with your tag, although EA has an Archimate profile.

Comment: sure, I couldnt create the archimate tag myself and wanted to adress other enterprise-architects as well. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the `enterprise-architect` is for the product EA from Sparx. It supports Archimate from profiles (so there might have been people to answer as well). But now your question is the first to be tagged with `archimate` :-) I'm pretty sure there'll be more to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider to model in the following way:

[image]

Explanation:

- "Application A" having a provided interface "Interface I"
- Connect "Interface I" to "Application B" using Flow relationship
- Connect "Data D" to the flow between "Interface I" and "Application B" using Association

BTW, [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com) support import models from Excel. You may transform the model in your Excel to fit into VP's format to perform the import. The most easy way to understand VP's Excel format is create several sample models and export it into Excel. You can then follow the format in exported Excel to fill in your model data and import them back. An example of importing SysML requirement models using Excel can be found at https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/uncategorized/importing-models-through-excel-file/ and this should give you idea about how it works.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I came up with as well (though the additional boxes for data kind of bloat the diagram) I also have that Excel guide at hand. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to export/import using components and "usedBy" relation **only**. sadly the relation(s) are not imported. Is there a way to simplify the visual syntax? I saw the "primitive" shapes. Is there a primitive shape for interface plus data ?

Comment: Maybe there are something wrong in the Excel file. I suggest you can send a support request to Visual Paradigm ( https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/ ) to let VP's support team take care of it.

Comment: Identified two issues with VP regarding import: 1) VP is sensitiv with cell-format. especially the IDs need to be TEXT in Excel as obtained by Excel-forumla TEXT(cell,"0"). 2) potentially you need to update the view in the model explorer manually by right-click: show / hide certain elements (e.g. relations). .... Sadly there is no logging or messages of what is happening during import.

Answer (score 1):

According to specification you should use instead of FLOW connector right SERVES connector.
But I who cares about semantics correct FLOW is better to understand for everyone.